# JPA @GeneratedValue is allways null

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using MySQL / JPA, and the auto-generated IDs on persisted entities are not becoming available even after commit. Here's the code where it happens:

```
synchronized (em.getTransaction()) {
    while (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        em.getTransaction().wait();
    }
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        em.merge(transmissor);
        em.merge(poco);
        em.flush();
        //em.refresh(poco);           
        System.out.println("ID: " + poco.getIdEstacao());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Some other unrelated code...
    em.getTransaction.commit();
    em.getTransaction.notify();
    System.out.println("ID: " + poco.getIdEstacao());
}
```

Both after `em.flush()` and after `em.getTransaction.commit()`, `poco.getIdEstacao` returns `null`. And if I try to `em.refresh(poco)` it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not refresh not managed object:unesp.lebac.aquitel.dataLink.enitity.Poco[ idEstacao=null ].
```

Any ideas why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: may you show your entity ?

Comment: PS: I think it's because you are using `merge()` -> try with `persist()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EntityManager.merge()` doesn't modify the object passed as argument, and doesn't make it managed. It copies the state of the object passed as argument to a managed entity instance, and returns this managed entity instance. So if you want to get the managed entity, you need

```
poco = em.merge(poco);
```

Comment: It also seems that the OP may be attempting to "merge" new instances.